# Android Drag and Drop. Positioning image after dragging

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, android-relativelayout

When I drag the ImageView it is put not on the place where I let go the finger. It is placed just below and to the right. I do not understand what's wrong.

Tried various options for ImageView positioning result is the same

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF8989"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

code

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnTouchListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.imageView1).getRootView().setOnDragListener(this);
        }

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

        float X = event.getX();
        float Y = event.getY();

        Log.d(LOGCAT, "X " + (int) X + "Y " + (int) Y);
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        view.setX(X);
        view.setY(Y);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

LogCat

```
12-04 23:44:40.548: D/myLogs(32658): Width image 72 Height image 72
12-04 23:44:40.558: D/myLogs(32658): ACTION_DROP X 216Y 390
12-04 23:44:40.568: D/myLogs(32658): Real position: X 180.0Y 354.0
12-04 23:44:40.598: D/myLogs(32658): Drag ended
12-04 23:44:41.928: D/myLogs(32658): Width image 72 Height image 72
12-04 23:44:41.928: D/myLogs(32658): ACTION_DROP X 442Y 329
12-04 23:44:41.948: D/myLogs(32658): Real position: X 406.0Y 293.0
12-04 23:44:41.968: D/myLogs(32658): Drag ended
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace

```
view.setX(X);
view.setY(Y);
```

with

```
view.setX(X-(view.getWidth()/2));
view.setY(Y-(view.getHeight()/2));
```

Comment: I did it. Earlier ImageView is inserted below and to the right, now just below.

Comment: Is it happens for all position? What is your view width,height and x,y

Comment: added log! view 72*72 standart android icon

Comment: As per the code, It is working properly. What is your problem? How can you say "just below" -your drop y position is 390 and your view y position is 354. Are you saying 390 and 354 is same?

Comment: If you want to see the changes more clear, try this code with big size image icon . You can see the difference now.

Comment: If I only touch the image, nothing more. Image moves down when I let go the finger.

Answer (score 3):

It's because it's placing the image's top left corner to where you realease.

To have it do what you want, basically you will need to subtract half of the image's width from X and half of it's height from Y.

So you should have something like this:

```
view.setX((X - (image.width / 2));
view.setY(Y - (image.width / 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

v.setX(me.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2));

v.setY(me.getRawY() - (float)(v.getHeight()* 1.5 / 2));

I found this solution as perfect answer where as dragging from the center of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone needs help with this: 
I tried it and found that the problem is with the rootview, if you give your layout an id (the one you are moving the image in) and than relace

```
findViewById(R.id.imageView1).getRootView().setOnDragListener(this);    
findViewById(R.id.imageView1).getRootView().findViewById(R.id.yourLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
```

That should do it.
for placing imageView in the middle try what others already said:

```
view.setX(X - iv.getWidth()/2);
view.setY(Y - iv.getHeight()/2) ;
```

This will place the imageView in the middle
Happy programming :)